# In MS Access VBA get Number of Processor Cores

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to get the number of processor cores available on a computer programmatically from within MS Access. As an example, the computer I work from most frequently has one processor with 6 cores. I want to grab the number '6' through VBA.

Thus far, I have found two ways to find this information through CMD. (1) I can execute the line `echo %NUMBER OF PROCESSORS%` and the result is `6` (simple and clean, I like it). (2) I have also tried `wmic cpu get numberorcores`, but the result of that prompt is as follows:

```
NumberOfCores
6
```

I intend to pipe the output to and read from the clipboard. The reason I use the clipboard is to avoid creating, reading, and deleting little text files of data. Prompt (2) works, I can successfully pipe the output to the clipboard and read it into a variable in VBA, but it's messy and I would have to parse the result to get the information I need. I would much prefer using prompt (1), but it's not working and the problem seems to be `echo`. I have tried using `shell()` and `CreateObject(WScript.Shell).Run` without success. The strings I have used to try to execute the `echo` prompt are as follows:

```
str = "echo %NUMBER OF PROCESSORS% | clip"
str = "cmd ""echo %NUMBER OF PROCESSORS% | clip"""
```

So, is there a way to successfully send an `echo` prompt to CMD through VBA and get a result?
Alternatively, is there a different way in VBA to get the number of cores?

TIA!

Comment: Have a look to the answer of Randy Shuman at this question stackoverflow.com/q/39274324/7599798. The VB.Script solution works also in VBA (just replace `WScript.Echo` with `Debug.Print`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Total Number of Cores from a computer WITHOUT HyperThreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274324/get-total-number-of-cores-from-a-computer-without-hyperthreading)

Comment: @June7 (and FunThomas, but I can only @ one person at a time it seems) It looks like the [Get Total Number of Cores from a computer WITHOUT HyperThreading](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39274324/7599798) thread probably has several good approaches that may work for my problem, so thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep it simple like this:

```
Dim result As Variant
result = Environ("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")
Debug.Print "Number of processors is " & result
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of the Environ method.